# Filter if CMS page is available for store view

Tags: magento-1.9, cms, filter, language

I was trying to filter CMS pages for my multi-language website.

I was filtering CMS pages, because some of them are only for one store.

So i was trying to filter like this:

```
$name_page = Mage::app()->getFrontController()->getRequest()->getRouteName();
if ($name_page == 'cms') {
    $cms_page = Mage::getSingleton('cms/page')->getIdentifier();
    $active = Mage::getModel('cms/block')->load($cms_page)->getIsActive();
    if($active != 1){
        return null;
    }
}
```

As far as i know, $active returns 1 or 0 for positive or negative.
Instead of these, my examples continue going to the stores with the cms in other languages.

Edit :

As first answer say:

```
  $name_page = Mage::app()->getFrontController()->getRequest()->getRouteName();
  if ($name_page == 'cms') {
        $cms_page = Mage::getSingleton('cms/page')->getIdentifier();
         $active = Mage::getModel('cms/block')->load($cms_page, 'identifier')->getIsActive();
        if(!$active){
            return null; 
        }
    }
```

I try this code, but my method is still returning the url.

---

My languages code:

```
<?php $_stores = $this->getAllStores(); ?>
<?php if (count($_stores) > 1): ?>
    <span class="div-list-lang">
    <?php echo ( $this->__('Switch language')); ?>
        <ul class="list-lang-ul">
        <?php foreach ($_stores as $_store): ?>
        <?php

        $_store->setTranslatedName(Mage::helper('catalog')->__($this->htmlEscape($_store->getName())));
        $country = strtolower(substr($this->htmlEscape($_store->getLocaleCode()), 3));

        $url = Mage::helper('youngdogs_alternate')->rewriteUrlForStore($_store->getId());
        if (!$url) {
            $url = $_store->getBaseUrl();
        }


        $identifier = Mage::getSingleton('cms/page')->getIdentifier();
        $pageId = Mage::getModel('cms/page')->checkIdentifier($identifier, $_store->getId());
        if($pageId){
            $url = $_store->getBaseUrl();
        }

        ?>

        <li>
            <a href="<?php echo $url ?>">
    <?php $store_id = $_store->getId();
    $logo_src = Mage::getStoreConfig('design/header/logo_src_small', $store_id)
    ?>
            <img class="mini-icon" src="<?php echo Mage::getBaseUrl('skin') ?>frontend/default/venauto/<?php echo $logo_src ?>" />
            <img class="mini-lang" src="<?php echo $this->getSkinUrl("images/flags/flag_$country.png") ?>" />
            <span class="span-lang" title="<?php echo $_store->getTranslatedName() ?>"><?php echo $_store->getTranslatedName() ?></span>
            </a>

        </li>
    <?php endforeach; ?>
        </ul>
    </span>
<?php endif; ?>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I don't really understand your question, but in case I got it right and your want to check if a page is available in a store and you have the page identifier you can do this:

```
$storeId = Mage::app()->getStore()->getId();
$pageId = Mage::getModel('cms/page')->checkIdentifier($identifier, $storeId);
if ($pageId) {
    //page is available
} else {
    //page does not exist or is not available
}
```

**[EDIT]**
If you want to get all the cms pages available for a certain store view, try this:

```
$collection = Mage::getModel('cms/page')->getCollection()
     ->addFieldToFilter('is_active', 1)
     ->addStoreFilter($storeId)

foreach ($collection as $page) {
    //do something with $page
}
```

Comment: I check your code, but dont works for me.
I will explain better:
I've made a language selector, but a lot of CMS of main page are not on other store views.
This CMS pages are just selected on the main page, but not for the others stores views.
I just want to filter in the selector menu language, that, when i open it to swap the language, if i am on CMS page that its only for the main page, the URL of the link have to be the BaseUrl for the other store views.

Understood?

Comment: Seams a bit clearer now. The code I wrote should still work. Just replace `$storeId = Mage::app()->getStore()->getId();` with what store id you need to check.

Comment: yeah, i have done when you says.
But the returned URL its the same still...
I check again but i'm sure i do it perfectly :(

Comment: Checked again, it makes that filter the URL for CMS, but it makes for other categories too, so, i have to implement the part of my code to check if its a CMS page ? -> LIKE :     $name_page = Mage::app()->getFrontController()->getRequest()->getRouteName();
  if ($name_page == 'cms') {  }   ???
Or any other recomendation??

Comment: @ntzz. See my update to the answer. Maybe it helps.

Comment: didn't work.
The problem is that this CMS is making a url like: PATH/index/cms/page.html

How can i prevent that don't happen? Could i make a 404 error for those pages?

Answer (score 1):

try this to load cms page by `identifier`

```
 $active = Mage::getModel('cms/page')->load($cms_page, 'identifier')->getIsActive();
```

Comment: and $active = 1 its the true return?

Comment: yes its true return...

Comment: So, i edit the post, because still there the problem.

Comment: use this code for check ..      if(!$active){
            return null;
        }

Comment: continue the error.

Where could i miss anything?
I check if the cms is perfectly on the store not?

Comment: add the store check follow #simon answer

Comment: change the answer check it now.

Comment: Still the problem.

I think this couldn't be a solution, maybe while i get the name page = 'cms' or maybe while i check if its active on the store view.

Comment: i check it by myself it is running and give me value of active. it is tested code

Comment: i have edit with my languages code exactly, to show how i was implementing the code.

Answer (score 0):

```
<?php
$name_page = Mage::app()->getFrontController()->getRequest()->getRouteName();
if ($name_page == 'cms') {
    $_store = Mage::app()->getStore();
    $cms_page = Mage::getSingleton('cms/page')->getIdentifier();
    $active = Mage::getModel('cms/page')->setStoreId($_store->getId())->load($cms_page, 'identifier')->getIsActive();
    if($active != 1){
        return null;
    }
}
```

I changed a few points:

- in the line `$active = ...`, you loaded the `cms/block` model. Instead,
  you need to use `cms/page`
- you need to load the cms page for a specific store, because it is
  very well possible, that the cms page is active for another store
  that you're looking at

You could also check, after you make sure that the right cms page is loaded in a positive scenario, if you need to do a `getIsActive()`-check at all. I think, when you set the store before loading, the `cms/page` instance returned will not even have an ID because it does not exist in the specified store.

Comment: still with the problem.
Could be other problem of my code ? Are you sure this code should works?

Comment: Hm, can you tell me the exact problem? For example, if you just call Mage::getModel('cms/page')->setStoreId($_store->getId())->load($cms_page, 'identifier'), does it return the correct cms page object?

Comment: Edit: If i use this code, it returns the exactly URL of the page.